# Equation behind the pixels grayscale

Tags: math, graphics

I have an image in grayscale and colored form,and
I want to know the pixel grayscale equation?
so I trace the same pixels on both images

red=119 green=198 blue=122
red=169 green=169 blue=169

red=0 green=133 blue=184
red=119 green=119 blue=119

red=119 green=74  blue=180
red=94    green=94  blue=94

what is the equation?

Comment: The last line should be red=94 green=94 blue=94, no ?

Comment: If you suppose that grayscale value is a linear combination of red, green, blue then you can build system and solve it using gaussian elimination or just use some online service.

Comment: @Super Chafouin yes, typing mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following equation brings the same results (round to the nearest integer) :

```
 gray = 0.1313*r + 0.6781*g + 0.1566*b;
```

(used [this site](http://www.1728.org/unknwn3.htm) for solving the 3 unknown equation as suggested in Nikita's comment)

Answer (score 2):

["Grayscale: Converting color to grayscale"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale)

[image: Grayscale Equation]

Note that the 0.299, 0.587 and 0.114 are absolutes for each colors weight as they all have different luminance. In simple terms, green is lighter than red and blue where blue is the darkest of three.
More info can be found [here](http://www.had2know.com/technology/rgb-to-gray-scale-converter.html).